# Is there a Python module for creating test files of specific sizes?

Tags: python, file, testing

I have a server that has files uploaded to it. I need to profile the upload/response time for various file sizes to that server i.e. how long it takes to upload a 10kb file, a 100mb file, and many other sizes. I want to avoid manually creating all of the files and storing them.

Is there a Python module that lets you create test files of arbitrary sizes? I'm basically looking for something that would work like:

```
test_1mb_file = test_file_module.create_test_file(size=1048576)
```

Comment: Doesn't it take longer to look for this kind of module than to come up with a 3 to 5-liner that perform the desired function?   Don't get me wrong, it is usually a good idea to reuse rather than reinvent, but when the task at hand is so trivial...

Answer (score 13):

You don't really need to write 1MB to create a 1MB file:

```
with open('bigfile', 'wb') as bigfile:
    bigfile.seek(1048575)
    bigfile.write('0')
```

On the other hand, do you really need a file at all? Many APIs take any "file-like object". It's not always clear whether that means `read`, `read` and `seek`, iterating by lines, or something else… but whatever it is, you should be able to simulate a 1MB file without creating more data than a single `read` or `readline` at a time.

PS, if you're not actually sending the files from Python, just creating them to use later, there are tools that are specifically designed for this kind of thing:

```
dd bs=1024 seek=1024 count=0 if=/dev/null of=bigfile # 1MB uninitialized
dd bs=1024 count=1024 if=/dev/zero of=bigfile # 1MB of zeroes
dd bs=1024 count=1024 if=/dev/random of=bigfile # 1MB of random data
```

Comment: in python 3.6 you need to use bigfile.write(b'0') as it requires a byte object to write to a byte stream

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
size = 1000
with open("myTestFile.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write(" " * size)
```

Comment: Note that if you want particularly large files, it might be worth splitting it into many smaller writes to stop you from running out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use something like

```
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as h:
    h.write("0" * 1048576)
    # Do whatever you need to do while the context manager keeps the file open
# Once you "outdent" the file will be closed and deleted.
```

This uses Python's [tempfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) module.

I used a `NamedTemporaryFile` in case you need external access to it, otherwise a `tempfile.TemporaryFile` would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

From @abarnert and @jedwards answers:

```
mb = 1
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tf:
    tf.seek(mb * 1024 * 1024 - 1)
    tf.write(b'0')
    tf.seek(0)
```