# Programatically Generating a file of a specific size in python without storing it anywhere

Tags: python, file, io

I know there are ways to create files of a specific size in Python: [Is there a Python module for creating test files of specific sizes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614774/is-there-a-python-module-for-creating-test-files-of-specific-sizes). Is there a way to create a "file like object" of a specific size that does not store any data to the memory or disk? I don't care what data is in the file. My use case is generating a large file for uploading to a certain API which takes "file like objects". In other words, random or other data can be read from the file up to the specified size, but this file is not stored to the disk or memory (the data is generated on the fly).

Comment: You could write a class easily enough that just returns `n` bytes of random data when someone attempts to `read()` `n` bytes of data from it. You'd only need to implement the methods that the API is actually going to call on it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to create a file-like object of a specified size you may either create a class implementing read() (as [Paul Griffiths](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2399879/paul-griffiths) suggested in his comment) or create a class extending the IOBase class which is the base class of File class in Python 3 (https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#module-io) and then implement read() and few other methods.